# How to pass variables from Controller to View without refreshing the Web Page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Whenever there is a call to Controller inside View, I want the Controller to return some variables to the View and do not refresh the View.

**Already know:**
return view("webpage" , compact('variable1', 'variable2') );

**What I expect to achieve:**
return compact('variable1', 'variable2');

This will not return the Webpage but only some of the variables.

---

**Edit:**
Thinking it from a complete different perspective, The question maybe rephrased as such

Is there a way to manipulate **REQUEST variables** of a web page from the controller? This way, i would be able to get new variables from the Controller without the web page being Refreshed.

Comment: @JellyBean You are telling me solution for data going from View(Form,as in example) -> Controller.
I want the opposite, data going from Controller -> View.

I am gonna edit the question to clear something.

Comment: A mix of [Guzzlehttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) would probably do the trick.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane Thanks for the reply, i will check it out.

Comment: Depending on how you set it up you can do a get request to your controller to get new variables, I use something similar with an auto complete function where I can get new data every time a user types something new.

Comment: @Jelly Bean Interesting, it might work for me. I will try to implement it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out much to work with, here is an example:

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your/route/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {getVariable: formInputValue},
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function () {
    console.log('Failed');
});
```

Controller Function:

```
public function getVariable(Request $request){
    $resault = $request->getVariable;
    return response()->json($results);
}
```

> Update: as per comments on this answer try this and see if it works for you.

In your controller where you fetch records instead of using a `->get();`
change it to `paginate(5);` this will return 5 records per page. and on your view at the bottom of your `</table>` add `{{ $variable->links() }}`

Comment: Although i m not familiar with Ajax(first time finding out what its used for) but this is definitely what i aimed for. Thanks a lot for taking so much of your time to keep updating me on this question. I am actually trying to make a Web page with "Page Numbers", so i thought if there could be a way to change pages (and fetch data from controller) without actually refreshing the web page. That's why i asked this question. This answer is good enough to guide me. Thanks.

Comment: could you post an image or a link of the page you working on so i can see what your page numbers are being used for. think i may have a better solution for you

Comment: The web page shows 5 entries. I intend to add "Page number: 1,2,3,4...last" at the end of webpage. Which ever page number user click on, that page number will be sent to Controller and That Controller will only return 5 Entries for that Page Number accordingly. If i use Ajax as you mentioned, i won't need to refresh the web page. Also, currently the web page is too basic, i am going to add further features as well, which will slow down the process if i keep refreshing web page for every "Page Number".
(P.S: Currently i am busy with exams, that's why not working on website right now.)

Comment: Answer updated for you, try it out sure it will save time and effort